# Calling a method from controller A in controller B in objective C

Tags: ios

I have a method called `someMethod` in controller A and I want to call in controller B.

How would I do this?

Comment: It depends.  We need more information.  What is the method doing?  You might need a class method, or you might need to create an instance of controller B and call the method on it.

Comment: It's usually a bad practice to call a controller's method from another controller. If this functionally needs to be shared, maybe move the logic to the service or model layer?

Answer (score 1):

Keep a pointer to your controllerA in your controllerB and do:

```
[self.controllerA performselector:@selector(someMethod) withObject:nil];
```

or just:

```
[self.controllerA someMethod];
```

But I agree with Shawn's comment, that this is not the best design - if you have functionality that needs to be shared between both view controllers, it might be better to move that functionality into a different class - your app delegate, maybe?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways of doing this.  One is to create a class method.  You create it like this:

```
+ (void) someMethod {
   //Do stuff
}
```

Call it like this:

```
[ControllerB someMethod];
```

Another way to do it is to create a new instance of controller B as Jeff Loughlin said, and call the method on it:

```
ControllerB *cb = [[ControllerB alloc] init];
[cb someOtherMethod];
```

Comment: You are calling a class method on an instance ...

Comment: Those are meant to be separate, sorry